# Qual è il significato di "schiacciare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nella versione in italiano dell'episodio *Il miracolo delle nozze di Cana* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> «E cosa è successo allora?» 
>  
>   «Oh disgrazia... abbiamo scoperto che un tino pieno di vino preparato per il banchetto del matrimonio, si è rovesciato in aceto!» 
>   «Tutto in aceto?! Boia che disgrazia! Sposa bagnata è fortunata, ma bagnata nell'aceto è disgraziata da **schiacciare** e cacciare via!»

Non capisco il significato di "schiacciare" in questo brano. Ho cercato questo verbo in parecchi dizionari, ma non sono riuscita a trovare niente che abbia senso in questo contesto. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Penso che il significato di schiacciare che più si avvicina tra quelli riportati da Treccani è opprimere (2. fig. a). Inoltre, se ti interessano le opere di Dario Fo e Franca Rame puoi trovare [qui](http://www.archivio.francarame.it/scheda.aspx?IDScheda=14389&IDOpera=106) il loro archivio online

Comment: A orecchio, preso insieme al "cacciare via" che segue, direi che si fa alla sposa quello che si fa a un oggetto inutile: lo si appallottola o lo si comprime in modo che occupi meno spazio possibile, e lo si butta.